# How to find a system of ODEs that give a specific function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the given system of equations:

\begin{equation}
x^2 + y^2 - z = C_1 \\
x y z=C_2
\end{equation}

and I want to find  a system of ODEs that yield the equation above as a solution.

The ODEs must be in the form:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=f_1(x,y,z)\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=f_2(x,y,z)\\
\frac{dz}{dt}=f_3(x,y,z)\\
\end{equation}

First I would sum the two at the top to one and get

$x^2+y^2-z+xyz=C_1+C_2$

Then it appears that the system of ODEs is really the gradient of the function f with respect to $t$. So I would just integrate this with respect to t for each function and divide them all by three, so their sum is equal to the equation at the top and get:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+xyz-C_1\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2-C_2\\
\frac{dz}{dt}=-z
\end{equation}

Integrating I get:

\begin{equation}
x=t(x^2+xyz-C_1)\\
y=t(y^2-C_2)\\
z=-tz\\
\end{equation}

But something tells me this is not right. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The sum of two equations is not equivalent to the two equations together.

Comment: A system is not always the sum of its components?

Comment: No. For example the system $x=2,y=3$ is not equivalent to $x+y=5.$ The latter has $x=1,y=4$ as a solution but the previous system does not.

Comment: I see your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First eliminate the constants by differentiation
$$
2x\dot x+2y\dot y-\dot z=0\\
\dot x yz+x\dot y z+xy\dot z=0
$$
This is a linear system for the derivatives. Its solution in regular points is a line. You now have the freedom to select any point on the line, as long as the resulting functions are continuous.

The obvious next step is the elimination of $\dot z$
$$
(2x^2y+yz)\dot x+(2xy^2+xz)\dot y=0.
$$

Comment: Thanks Lutz, this is clearly a good answer.

Comment: Lutz, basically you just take the gradient of each of the two functions right? Do you sum them up together at the end?

Comment: The cross product of the gradients as derivatives vector. The gradients are orthogonal to the surfaces, and the cross product orthogonal to both gradients, thus tangent to both surfaces.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thanks